# mapbox's node sqlite3 - using LIKE with parameterization correctly

Tags: node.js, sqlite, parameterization

So I spent more time than I'd like to disclose finding out this little bit of undocumented gem:

So when you're doing something like: `db.all(sql,params,callback)`

**this wont work**

where params and sql is something like:

```
var params = { $param1 : 'some string' };
var sql = 'select * from FOO where FOO.name LIKE "%$param1%"';
```

Answered below.

Comment: Correct Codeformatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this works**

```
var params = { $param1 : '%' + 'some string' + '%' };
var sql = 'select * from FOO where FOO.name LIKE $param1';
```

I hope this helps someone out there - because no amount of googling would have got me to this answer.